# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse using JDI Debug Model version3.17.0.v20201117-1145

Tags: java, eclipse, jdi

I was using Eclipse 2020-12 with OpenJDK 14 under Windows 10 without problem until some days ago, now I can't open or use any function which use JDI due to a `ClassNotFoundException` (ie: setup run configurations, launch a server, open debug preferences, etc).

I don't remember doing nothing in particular and to be sure I've done a clean install with a brand new workspace: after the first run, leaving eclipse untouched, the problem reappear: simply opening eclipse, going to java debug preferences, closing eclipse, reopening it and doing the same thing trigger the error.

This is the exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/IJavaHotCodeReplaceListener
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.lambda$0(WorkbenchPlugin.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1193)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4001)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3629)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug (397).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.JDIDebugPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1011)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jdi/VMDisconnectedException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.JDIDebugPlugin.start(JDIDebugPlugin.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException cannot be found by org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.17.0.v20201117-1145
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 98 more
```

and there is the session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.18.0.I20201202-1800
java.version=14.0.1
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_UY
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

It seems to me some kind of incompatibility between org.eclipse.jdt.debug version 3.17.0.v20201117-1145 and JDK. I'm going to do further tests, but if someone can point me to a solution it will be very appreciated.

Should I open a bug?

**UPDATE:** using OpenJDK 15 resolves the issue, so it's definitely something between latest Eclipse and OpenJDK 14.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a fresh Eclipse installation without additional plugins and with a fresh workspace?

Comment: Yes: I've done a clean install with a brand new workspace, after the first run the problem reappear